# What different breakpoint icons mean in Eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, debugging, breakpoints

When working with breakpoints in Eclipse I sometimes notice that they have different icons / annotations (markers on left sidebar). Sometimes it's just a blue ball, sometimes it has a checkmark on it and sometimes it is crossed. What do all these annotations mean?

Answer (score 142, accepted):

- blue ball: regular breakpoint, active (possibly with a hit count set)
- empty ball (i.e. white): breakpoint has been disabled (remove checkmark in the breakpoint view, or `disable` in context menu)
- diagonal line through breakpoint: all breakpoints have been disabled (button `skip all breakpoints` in breakpoint view)
- question mark next to breakpoint: a condition is active for this breakpoint (look under properties of the breakpoint)

Comment: I had trouble finding the breakpoint view - as of Juno
Window->Show View->Other->Debug->Breakpoints

Comment: Thanks I couldn't figure out why all the breakpoints where deactivated, thanks to you I found the skip all button :)

Answer (score 17):

The tick means that the breakpoint has been successfully set. I think it may only appear when you're doing remote debugging; when you add a breakpoint, it starts out as a plain ball, but once the JPDA agent in the remote system has been told about it, and has confirmed it's set, then it gets a tick.

Comment: Thanks for that, I couldn't find the meaning of the tick mark.

Answer (score 11):

I have created an example code with explanation inline.

```
public class Breakpoints {
    int field1; // watchpoint - suspend when field1 is read
    int field2; // watchpoint - suspend when field1 is written
    int field3; // watchpoint - suspend when field1 is read or written

    public void method() {
        int x;
        x = 10; // suspend before this line is executed 
        x = 11; // same as above but this breakpoint is temporarily disabled
        for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
            x = i; // conditional breakpoint - suspend when i==5
        }
    }
}
```

[image: Eclipse breakpoint icons]

Once you select `Skip All Breakpoints` in the Breakpoints view (`Window | Show Viev | Debug | Breakpoints`), all the icons become diagonally struck through like this:

[image: Eclipse breakpoint icons Skip All]

Answer (score 8):

I think answer given by @sleske is explaining all things except for :

*Blue Ball with Tick* : Breakpoint is successfully set because Your Source code matches with the Byte Code and debug control will reach there.

*Only Blue Ball* : Source code differs from Byte code (May be you are running a older Snapshot of code). Control will never reach at this breakpoint. You will have to update your JARs to get control to these breakpoints.

Answer (score 6):

Adding to earlier answers. The *small white **`c`** over a green ball* icon means that the breakpoint is at the class level.

[image: Class Load Breakpoint]

[Eclipse Help](http://help.eclipse.org/mars/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.jdt.doc.user%2Freference%2Fmenus%2Frun%2Fref-add_class_load_breakpoint.htm)

Answer (score 2):

If you see a "T" on the blue ball, It means a triggering point for remote debugging [image]

Answer (score 1):

In Eclipse toolbar press **Help** > **Help Contents**

A new window will open, simply type **JDT Icons**. Select the result with the same name.

A list of icons with their respective meaning shaw appear. Scroll down until you find the **Debugger** section.