# Eclipse PyDev Breakpoints Show an Different Icon and Don't Work

Tags: eclipse, pydev

Breakpoints have been working for me for many weeks, but yesterday they stopped working.  When I create a breakpoint icon shown is not the usual magnifying glass, but instead is the magnifying glass with a line through it.

I tried the suggestions in [pydev breakpoints not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9486871/pydev-breakpoints-not-working)

E.g.

```
import sys
print 'current trace function', sys.gettrace()
```

which reports "current trace function main.PyDB object at 0x101416090>>
"

I tried accessing breakpoints in another Python project and the breakpoints there have the same problem.  Restarting Eclipse, the Mac and reinstalling PyDev had no effect.

I tried installing PyDev in another Eclipse installation on my Mac and breakpoints in Python work find there.

Any ideas, anyone?

Answer (score 10):

screenshot should be like this:

[image]

That is because you have enable "skip all breakpoints" in Eclipse, show it here: 
[image]

Also useful info:

[skip all breakpoints in eclipse](http://help.eclipse.org/juno/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.jdt.doc.user%2Freference%2Fviews%2Fbreakpoints%2Fref-skipall_viewaction.htm)

[different breakpoints annotations meanings in eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4079000/what-different-breakpoint-annotations-mean-in-eclipse)

another alias question:[eclipse-pydev-breakpoint-does-not-stop-and-show-a-different-icon](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16851290/eclipse-pydev-breakpoint-does-not-stop-and-show-a-different-icon)

Answer (score 3):

If it shows a line through it, you probably clicked the 'skip all breakpoints' in the breakpoints view... in which case it'd be a matter of clicking that option again?

If that's not it, please post a screenshot and take a look at your error log for something related...