# eclipse pydev breakpoint does not stop and show a different icon?

Tags: eclipse, pydev, breakpoints

Environment: Eclipse 3.7.2 Pydev 2.7.1

several weeks ago , when I debugging a python project in eclipse with pydev , it can set break points and work  successfully. But recently when I debugging a similar python project , after set break point , I find the icon is different with previous  and the break point did not work , it won't stop at break point.
abnormal icon show as: 
[image]

I also find another similar problem [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11035850/eclipse-pydev-breakpoints-show-an-different-icon-and-dont-work)  and i have answered question there. It is because you have enabled the skip all break points in Eclipse. shows as: 
[image]

Comment: I have find the reason because  I  enable the option _skipp_all_breakpoint in Eclipse. see it [here](http://postimg.org/image/ovhwpvnax/)

Comment: you can write it as an answer if it is really helpful and accept the answer it will help others with the same problem to get an answer

Comment: yes , i have answered that question, I wil duplicate this one and add more info to that one.