# Why is the breakpoint marked with a backslash in eclipse CDT editor?

Tags: c++, c, eclipse, ide, breakpoints

[image]

In the picture, I have set two breakpoints, and the breakpoint marks are displayed as two small balls with backslashes, rather than just two small balls.

Why is it? and how to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It should be similar to [this annotation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4079103/6309):

> diagonal line through breakpoint: all breakpoints have been disabled (button skip all breakpoints in breakpoint view)

See "[Skip All Breakpoints](http://help.eclipse.org/juno/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.jdt.doc.user%2Freference%2Fviews%2Fbreakpoints%2Fref-skipall_viewaction.htm)".

Also [visible in PyDev](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11035850/6309) (so not specific to CDT):

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/bgVeq.png]

Comment: Why are the breakpoints still enabled and can be hit even they are marked as "skipped all breakpoints"?

Comment: @xmllmx because they are not disabled, they are only skipped.

Comment: What does it mean by "skipped"? When I debug this program, it will still break on all the breakpoints. If they are skipped, then they cannot be hit. However, they are indeed hit!

Comment: @xmllmx is the button "skip all breakpoints" pushed in the Breakpoints view?

Comment: @xmllmx did you activated tracepoints instead of breakpoints? (http://wiki.eclipse.org/CDT/User/FAQ#How_can_I_trace_my_application_using_C.2FC.2B.2B_Tracepoints.3F)

Comment: @xmllmx And if you unset the skip all breakpoints (no more crossed-lines), and re-enable that button, would those breakpoints now be actually skipped? Or would your program still  stops at those?

Comment: @xmllmx and what version of GDB are you using?

Comment: I don't know. I use MinGW with gcc 4.9.0

Comment: @xmllmx did you try my previous comment? "if you unset the skip all breakpoints (no more crossed-lines), and re-enable that button, would those breakpoints now be actually skipped? Or would your program still stops at those?"

Comment: I indeed did as you tell me, but the breakpoints were still hit.