# Meaning of crossed out breakpoint in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, debugging, breakpoints

what is the meaning of this break point icon? Why is it crossed out?

[image]

Comment: You need to take a look at this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4079103/2024761).

Answer (score 21, accepted):

That means you have selected to skip all breakpoints the breakpoints in eclipse via the small button in eclipse's breakpoint view. The button have the same icon.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Such a stupid reason... but I don't remember ever pushing this button before. Is it a default setting? Or could I have pressed accidentally a keyboard shortcut which did it?

Comment: In my Eclipse version, this damn button is beside the save icon. I swear I haven't pressed it.

Answer (score 1):

That means you have skipped the break-point.

Check [this](http://help.eclipse.org/juno/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.jdt.doc.user%2Freference%2Fviews%2Fbreakpoints%2Fref-skipall_viewaction.htm) article to see how

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you have enabled the Skip All Breakpoints option

Answer (score 0):

Okey I find the reason why.

cause is **skip all breakpoints** selection.

Answer (score 0):

That means . That break point is not active.
In eclips we have option to active and detective the break point as we required.

Hope you get your answer.