# Eclipse breakpoint blue circle vs glass icon?

Tags: java, eclipse

[image]When i put the breakpoint in my code , sometime i just see the blue circle and sometime glass icon . Whats the difference?

I am using eclipse lune

Comment: Your answer is probably here :  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4079000/what-different-breakpoint-icons-mean-in-eclipse

Comment: Somehow i am not able to paste the image from opera. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4079000/what-different-breakpoint-icons-mean-in-eclipse does not answer my question

Comment: @Tunaki please have a look at screenshot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Blue ball: regular breakpoint, active (possibly with a hit count set)
- Blue ball with a tick: is only shown when you have an active debug session at that line. It means your breakpoint is active and attached to the bytecode running in debug mode. Debugger cannot (and will never) stop at breakpoints without that "tick".

Comment: @please have a look at screenshot

Comment: @scott miles take a look at answer now